# How to reload OnsurfaceCreated in glsurfaceview when i click a button in opengl es?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have working 3D model rendering with opengl-es.I was rendered model successfully when activity launch. I want to recall onSurfaceCreated for rendering another model in a same activity when i click a button.is it possible to call OnSurfaceCreated Method

Comment: Put the code which is currently in onSurfaceCreated() in a method. Call that method in both onSurfaceCreated() and the click listener of your button, DONE.

Comment: ok thank you i will try.

Comment: I have tried your solution.but app crashed with java.lang.RuntimeException Error creating shader. when i call the method from button click.

Comment: Probably the shader creation has to be left out from your method and only left inside the onSurfaceCreated() one, before the call to your method.

Comment: you mean shader will only inside into onSurfaceCreated call?

Comment: I mean the shader **assignment**. The object variable has to be created where it is visible to every method. Or you'll get a NPE.

Comment: if i compile shader outside of the gl thread it returns shader compilation error what can i do?

Comment: What can I say, not seeing any code?

Comment: did you find any solution regarding it?